# Application error when creating simple web service using Spring Boot

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, cxf, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am getting below error when creating a simple web service that returns "hello" string

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

My webservice endpoint:

```
@WebService
        public class HelloWs {
            @WebMethod
            public String hello() {
                return "hello";
            }
      }
```

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;
    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        Endpoint endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new HelloWs());
        endpoint.publish("/hello");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

My `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `mvn spring-boot:run` then cxf web services are host at /services/*, Thus at url `http://localhost:8080/services` you will find list of the cxf endpoints, in your case it will be only one. And you get wsdl at location `http://localhost:8080/services/hello?wsdl`

If you are deploying to any app server add context path before services.